Bedeutung von "Es ist Krieg"
Ich lese gerade Die Vermessung der Welt von Daniel Kehlmann. Ein kurzer Ausschnitt:

[Gauß fragte] in der Universität nach dem Baubeginn des
Observatoriums.
Man höre zur Zeit nicht viel vom Ministerium, sagte der Beamte.
Hannover sei weit. Genaues wisse man nicht. Falls er das vergessen
habe, es sei Krieg.

Diese "Es ist Krieg"-Formulierung habe ich auch schon anderswo in diesem Buch gelesen. Ich gehe davon aus, dass es so viel bedeutet wie "Es gibt Krieg", "Ein Krieg passiert gerade", "Wir sind gerade im Krieg" oder Ähnliches, obwohl ich mich freuen würde, wenn ihr das bestätigen würdet. Angenommen, dass ich die Sache richtig verstehe, ist dieser Gebrauch von "Es ist" nur für diesen besonderen Ausdruck über Krieg bestimmt, oder gibt es andere Situationen, in denen "Es ist" quasi als "Es gibt" benutzt wird?

Meines Erachtens bedeutet sein hier stattfinden; siehe DWDS unter 5. Wenn zwei Schüler miteinander sprechen, kann der Lehrer sagen:

Es ist Unterricht!

Damit ist gemeint, daß das Verhalten der Schüler nicht angemessen ist: Während der Unterricht stattfindet, können sie sich nicht unterhalten, als wären sie in der Pause. Es gibt Unterricht hätte in dieser Situation nicht die erwünschte Wirkung.

Es ist Krieg.

Im Gegensatz zu es gibt Krieg findet der Krieg gerade statt. Deshalb hat man die Auswirkungen des Krieges im Sinn, welche auch immer das sein mögen. Im Ausgangsbeispiel vielleicht, daß in Kriegszeiten das Ministerium zu beschäftigt ist, um sich um den Bau von Observatorien zu kümmern.
Ein Klassiker ist der folgende Spruch, in dem es natürlich nicht darum geht, daß Kriege existieren, sondern daß gerade einer stattfindet.

Stell dir vor, es ist Krieg und keiner geht hin.

Parallel zu Unterricht paßt natürlich auch:

Ist schon wieder Pause?

Gemeint ist, daß schon wieder Pause gemacht wird. Oder, wenn man die Nachbarn staubsaugen hört, sie also gerade putzen:

Bei denen ist heute Großputz!

Die letzten beiden Beispiele zeigen auch, daß es sich bei es in diesen Sätzen nicht um ein formales Subjekt (wie bei es gibt) handelt, sondern um einen Platzhalter, der verschwindet, wenn es kein Vorfeld gibt oder dieses von einem anderen Element besetzt wird.
Besonders deutlich wird die Bedeutung, daß etwas geschieht, auch in Fällen wie den folgenden.

War etwas? (= ist etwas passiert?)
Da muss etwas gewesen sein! (= da muss etwas passiert sein)


Der Ausdruck ist nicht nur mit Krieg verbunden.
Es ist

warm/kalt
hell/dunkel
Januar/.../Dezember
Montag/.../Sonntag
Frühling/Sommer/Herbst/Winter
Tag/Nacht
Frieden/Krieg
12:00/13:15/... Uhr
Tag der offenen Tür
Elternabend
Ostern/Weihnachten/Ramadan/Hanukkah
etc.

Es bedeutet weniger "es gibt" sondern beschreibt mehr einen Status, eine Situation oder ein Event.

Kleiner Zusatz: Es gibt Krieg würde eher bedeuten, dass ein Krieg bevorsteht.
